# typescript override generic method

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

How can I overload a generic method with concrete type?
It seems to work if I specify R at class level ie Foo but not at method's level.

```
class Foo {
    find<R>(arg: R[]): R[] {
        return arg;
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    find(arg: string[]) {
        return super.find(arg);
    }
}
```

Gives the following error

> Property 'find' in type 'Bar' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Foo'.
>   Type '(arg: string[]) => string[]' is not assignable to type '(arg: R[]) => R[]'.
>     Types of parameters 'arg' and 'arg' are incompatible.
>        Type 'R[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
>          Type 'R' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2416)

Answer (score 2):

The compiler does not allow it because it would create a hole in the type system. Consider the following:

```js
function findNumbers(obj: Foo) {
    return obj.find([1, 2, 3]);
}

findNumbers(new Bar());
```

`findNumbers` should accept an instance of `Bar` (since `Bar extends Foo`) but `Bar.prototype.find` can only accept `string[]` whereas `Foo.prototype.find` accepts any array. In TypeScript's type system an instance of a subclass should be able to do everything an instance of a superclass can. In your example `Bar.prototype.find` wouldn't be able to accept a `number[]` whereas `Foo.prototype.find` could. Therefore your `Bar` would not be a valid subclass of `Foo`.